# How many stars are there in a Globular Cluster of 10^5 solar masses?

Tags: observational-astronomy, globular-clusters

I was wondering whether there is an easy way to approximate the number of stars in a Globular Cluster (GC) with 10^5 solar masses.

Can one, for instance just assume the GC is made of sun-like stars and therefore has 10^5 stars? 
Or is this too simple?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mean mass of the initial mass function is ~0.3 solar masses ([Maschberger 2013](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0939)).  A GC with 10^5 solar masses will therefore have ~3 x 10^5 stars in it.  Since the most massive stars will already have died in a GC, the mean mass of the present-day mass distribution of the GC will actually be slightly lower, implying a slightly larger number of stars, but this will be a relatively small correction (certainly not more than a factor of 3).

Comment: Do you really expect a factor as large as up to 3 for the correction of dead stars? I don't think this is much more than a few, perhaps 20%.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the estimations I was dealing with, it was actually already good enough to say that there are 10^5 stars inside. However, it is of course better to have a reference!